# Struggling to understand AJAX w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, github

I am very new to programming.

I am trying to output a list of (my two empty) GitHub repositories into a `<p>` with `id="repos"`. When I run the code, I receive the error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined at XMLHttpRequest.gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange

And I'll receive this error for every the other two keys I want to pull the value from (full_name & html_url).

Can someone give me some insight as to how I can make this code work? it needs to be Javascript- its for a class. Thanks you!

```js
let gitHubRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
gitHubRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/billythesailor/repos', true);

gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var repos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        var output = '';
        for(var i in repos){
            output +=
            '<ul>' +
            '<li>ID: ' +id[i]+'</li>' +
            '<li>Full Name: ' +full_name[i]+'</li>' +
            '<li>URL: ' +html_url[i]+'</li>'+
            '</ul>'
        }

        document.getElementById('repos').innerHTML = output;
    }
}

gitHubRequest.send();
```

Comment: What are these `id` and `full_name` and `html_url` variables? You've never defined them. If you meant to iterate over the response, use `forEach` instead

Comment: They are properties from https://api.github.com/users/billythesailor/repos.

I was basing the script off of this youtube video which outputs a list of github users. https://youtu.be/82hnvUYY6QA?t=44m1s

Comment: Ah, that seemed to resolve the properties not being defined, but now I receive this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange

Thoughts?

Comment: I've answered below, but your example has no html on the page, so `document.getElementById('repos')` will return null. And the the repo data needs to be read off of the element in the repos array, like `repos[i].id`

Comment: Properties of objects are *not* standalone variables.

Comment: @GarrettJohnson's answer is correct, TIL I have more to learn :) I was thinking of `for...of`

Comment: @Drazisil, you have less to learn than I do, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `id`, `full_name`, and `html_url` are fields on the repo objects, but you're accessing them as defined arrays. So `id[i]` needs to change to `repos[i].id` and so on. I've updated your example below!

```js
let gitHubRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
gitHubRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/billythesailor/repos', true);

gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var repos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var output = '';
        for(var i in repos){
            output +=
            '<ul>' +
            '<li>ID: ' + repos[i].id +'</li>' +
            '<li>Full Name: ' + repos[i].full_name +'</li>' +
            '<li>URL: ' + repos[i].html_url +'</li>'+
            '</ul>'
        }

        document.getElementById('repos').innerHTML = output;
    }
}

gitHubRequest.send();
```

```html
<div id="repos"></div>
```

Also, if you're new to Javascript and interested in making ajax requests, I'd look into the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is bit cleaner to use.

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/billythesailor/repos')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(repos => {
    // do stuff with the repo data!
  });
```

Comment: I think Fetch API my next course. 

However, with the code above, I receive a new error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange (script.js:25)
gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange @ script.js:25
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ script.js:29

Comment: Running the snippet works, though, right? The code `document.getElementById('repos')` expects html to be on the page and to find an element with the id of `repos`. `<div id="repos"></div>`, for example. You need to add that to your html to work.

Comment: I was at work, and trying to quickly debug on my end with your code. I forgot that I had commented out the <div> that it was outputting to yesterday while I was working on other things, but I just got home and tried it again. IT DOES WORK! Thank you so much. And thank you for explaining this to me, instead of just posting different code or name-dropping terminology I haven't familiarized myself with yet. 

Thank you , thank you, thank you!